# Upper bound of number of prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

If I'm given a  prime number $p$: is there an upper bound to the number of prime factors of $p−1$? Alternatively, is there a way to calculate the number of prime factors of $p−1$ without actually calculating the factors?

Comment: One cannot expect a bound better than a typical integer. Indeed, there is nothing preventing $p-1$ from having as many prime factors as is allowed for a number that size.

Comment: So far the largest prime found which is one more than the product of the first $n$ primes has $n=392113$  and so $p-1$ has that many distinct prime factors.

Comment: While the Proth prime $10223 \times 2^{31172165} + 1$ clearly is one more than a number with $31172166$ prime factors counted with repetition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reiterate Stanley Yao Xiao's comment, one should not expect that $p-1$ has any more or less prime factors than a typical integer of size $p$. For an arbitrary integer $n$, the bound
$$
\omega(n) \ll \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}
$$
is standard (see Hardy and Wright's "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" for a proof of this). Here $\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

It is known that integers of the form $p-1$ have about the same number of divisors as typical integers $n$ on average. The Titchmarsh divisor problem states that
$$
\sum_{p\leq x} \tau(p-1) \sim C x
$$
for some explicit constant $C$, where $\tau(n)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $n$. Stated differently, we may write
$$
\frac{1}{\pi(x)} \sum_{p\leq x} \tau(p-1) \sim C \log x
$$
by the Prime Number Theorem, and so $p-1$ has $\asymp \log x$ divisors on average for $p\leq x$, the same as for all integers up to $x$ (up to a constant factor).

Comment: It's worth probably pointing out that @OfirGorodetsky's previous answer here ( https://mathoverflow.net/a/436137/ ) is also relevant, especially the remarks about the central limit theorem.

Comment: @JoshuaStucky I deleted my first comment because it was not actually accurate in terms of describing the papers I mentioned (feel free to delete yours as well). I wrote it because the last line of the answer mentions "prime factors" where I think it should be "divisors".

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky Ahh, didn't see that typo. Corrected!

Comment: Also, since one has $\omega(m) \gg \frac{\log m}{\log \log m}$ for infinitely many $m$ (in particular, primorials), it follows from Linnik's theorem that one also has $\omega(n) \gg \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$ for any infinitely many $n$ of the form $p-1$ (take $p$ to be the first prime in the progression $1 \hbox{ mod } m$ for $m$ a primorial; Linnik's theorem tells us that $\log (p-1) \asymp \log n$).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem .  So the upper bound $\omega(n) \ll \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$ is sharp up to constants for $n=p-1$.